# Oracle (xe) 10 vs 11 . Have I lost the SQL tuning pages ? Am I going out of my mind?

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle10g

Ok .. so perhaps the title needs calming down a bit.

Basically I am after the XE 11g equivalent of [the pages that you can see here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/getstart.htm#BABHJAGE), in which you can then navigate to stuff like "top 50 queries" and "longest running queries", etc etc. For the life of me, I can't find that on the most recent XE edition.

Please can someone direct me to where I might find these very useful admin pages ! Or was I imagining it all along :-/

Edit: [These are the pages I am after](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/monitoring.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Visiting [the equivalent page in the 11g version of Oracle 2 Day DBA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/monitoring.htm#XEDBAMonitoring), I see that the monitoring you are referring to is now done in [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html), rather than via web interface. It appears the web interface you were previously using is completely gone in 11g.

Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: That's what I thought - that it had just "gone". Great.

Comment: On the bright side, they don't seem to have _removed_ any functionality, at least that I can discern from a quick look. It's all just been rearranged.

Answer (score 1):

[These documentation pages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/toc.htm) for are for XE 11.2, they look very similar in content to what you asked for.

I found them on [this part of the Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/documentation/index.html).

Comment: I think the best parts of all the monitoring are via SQL developer (which was an option) but I would prefer the web interface equivalent.

Comment: To me, it looks like they shifted the focus of their documentation away from web interface administration. This page looks like the direct equivalent of the chapter 8 page you linked to in your question: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/monitoring.htm#XEDBAMonitoring But indeed, some of the info that used to be there is now gone.